How to use virtual ICollection in ASP.NET Core
I'm working on comment on the product details page. I want to display all the comments of that product. Usually, I use ViewBag to select all the comments :
ViewBag.Comment = await _context.ProductComments
                                .Where(n => n.ProductId  == sp.ProductItems.ProductId)
                                .ToListAsync();

And then in the view :
IEnumerable<ProductComment> listComment = ViewBag.Comment as IEnumerable<ProductComment>;

@foreach (var comment in listComment)
{
    <div>
        <p>@comment.Detail</p>
        <p>@comment.CreatedBy</p>
        <p>@comment.CreateDate</p>
    </div>
}

But now I notice that in the Product model class, I have a property
public virtual ICollection<ProductComment> ProductComments { get; set; }

because one product can have many comments. I try to use this property in the view and changed the foreach like this:
@foreach (var comment in Model.ProductItems.Product.ProductComments)
{
    <div>
        <p>@comment.Detail</p>
        <p>@comment.CreatedBy</p>
        <p>@comment.CreateDate</p>
    </div>
}

But the comment section blank img. I search in chat GPT and YouTube but still doesn't work.
Is there any right way or am I misunderstanding something? I'd really appreciate any instruction. Thank you for reading

Why is the image a link, and not embedded in the question?

How is the Product loaded? Since ProductComments is a virtual collection, it will not be loaded automatically, unless you specifically include it (using .Include(p => p.ProductComments))

Sorry I will change

Solutions : You need to include ProductComments in the Controller
var product = await _context.ProductVariations
    .Include(n => n.ProductItems.Product.ProductComments)
    .Include(n => n.ProductItems.Product.Category)

